# Distorted colours after conversion

Tags: python, opencv, pycairo

I'm trying to write a simple Python program to draw on pictures/videos with OpenCV. I don't like build-in drawing tools (in future I'd like to use gradients etc.), so I decided to use Gizeh (vector graphics library based on Cairo - https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh). I'm loading picture/frame and after creating surface from image (and few conversions since cv2 is using BGR instead of RGB) colours become distorted. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import gizeh
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('karin.jpg')
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
surface = gizeh.Surface.from_image(img_rgb)
marker = gizeh.ellipse(w=40,h=10,fill=(1,0,0),xy=[50,50])
marker.draw(surface)
img_final = cv2.cvtColor(surface.get_npimage(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('output', img_final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Example - Before and after conversion]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix this? Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT:

I had problems with creating surface from image. After long research I found this:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7225

I've edited line 53 in gizeh.py as it is recommended in this thread:

```
arr += np.add(arr, image.flatten(), out=arr, casting="unsafe")
```

Could this cause problems with this distortions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be somewhere in the library itself. It even threw and error for me when I tried to import it after the installation. But you can achieve the same result just with opencv which you are already using for reading the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('karin,jpg')
center_coordinates = (120, 100) 
axesLength = (100, 50) 
angle = 30
startAngle = 0
endAngle = 360 
color = (0, 0, 255) 
thickness = -1
img = cv2.ellipse(img, center_coordinates, axesLength, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color, thickness) 
cv2.imshow('output', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As I wrote - I want to use different, more elastic tool, because I'd like to use, for example, gradients. I've edited question with little change I had to make in library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem occurs because of some problems during library installation. I tried this code on another PC and it works, so after reinstallation everything is fine.